# How to assign array values to the n-1 location in the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I have an array like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I shuffle it to get this: `[1, 5, 4, 2, 3]`.

**The Goal: Assign each value in the array to the n-1 location in the array**

In other words, I need the number 1 to be in 1st position, 2 in 5th, 3 in 4th, 2 in 5th, and 3 in 6th.

For example, the output of this one would be: `[1, 4, 5, 3, 2]`.

Is there a built in function for this or a simple code that can accomplish this goal?

What I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import random
array = np.arange(1,6)
print(array)
random.shuffle(array)
print(array)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple one-liner to do it:

```
array[array-1] = np.arange(array.size)+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have all values in the `range(1, len(a))`, use numpy indexing:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([1, 5, 4, 2, 3])
# or for a shuffled array
# b = a.copy() ; np.random.shuffle(b)

out = np.zeros_like(a)
out[b-1] = a
```

Output: `array([1, 4, 5, 3, 2])`

Comment: I guess this would work if I assign `b = random.shuffle(a)`

Comment: @GT-R yes, I just used your example. But the real code to shuffle should be `b = a.copy() ; np.random.shuffle(b)` or `b = np.random.choice(a, a.shape, replace=False)` as `shuffle` is in place.

Comment: @GT-R `random.shuffle` is an in-place operation. So the result of `b = random.shuffle(a)` is that `a` has been shuffled and `b` is None.

Comment: oh, did't realize that, I guess I don't need `a` anymore so I can just use `random.shuffle(a)`

Comment: Well you need it as a source of values for the indexing. What are you trying to do anyway? Seems a bit odd to shuffle the values as indices to just reorder the array itself.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to the problem. I just need an output for some neural network modeling simulation I'm working on

Comment: @GT-R just note that the accepted answer is exactly the same as my suggestion, it just used a range inline instead of the range as you specified in your question…